# Remote execute bash scripts that needs input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am using SSH command to execute the bash scripts remotely:

```
ssh user@server 'bash -s' < $script_dir/script.sh
```

And inside the script.sh, I will have the command like below:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id postgres@$sqlserver
ssh postgres@$sqlserver -C true
```

And also

```
printf "Creating user in postgresql server...\n"
createuser -s -P username
```

Which need user's input, but I found when I execute the command from the remote server, it will skip getting the users' input and failed.

Another one is:

```
printf "Please enter your barman server name: \n" ; read -s barmanserver
```

Which cannot read user's input neither

I know that the script seems cannot read the other terminal's input, but can anyone help me find a solution if I need the user input to continue?

Thanks a lot!!

Eva

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in the past. I am not quite sure why I installed sshpass though.

```
apt-get install sshpass -y
echo "Adding users to new VMs"
adduser adminuser
echo "changing user password"
echo "adminuser:password" | chpasswd
adduser adminuser sudo
```

It does work, but it gives you some warning.